# How can I run synchronous long running operations in EventMachine without blocking the reactor?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, fibers

I'd like to run a series of `Proc`s, in a specified order (i.e., they can't run asynchronously). Some of them may take an arbitrarily long amount of time.

My code is running within a context of an EventMachine reactor.
Is there a known idiom for writing this kind of code *without* blocking the main reactor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @maniacalrobot said, using `EM.defer/deferrable` lets the procs be run without blocking the reactor.
But then you enter "callback hell" when you need to run several procs serially.

I know two solutions to make the code more readable: promises and fibers.

**Promises** gives you a nice API to compose asynchronous calls, there are a lot of good articles out there, including:

- http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

**Fibers** are a more ruby specific tool which makes your code look synchronous while doing asynchronous things.

Here is an helper method to execute a proc asynchronously (deferred) but still block the calling code without blocking the main reactor (that's the magic of Fibers):

```
def deferring(action)
  f = Fiber.current

  safe_action = proc do
    begin
      res = action.call
      [nil, res]
    rescue => e
      [e, nil]
    end
  end

  EM::defer(safe_action, proc { |error, result| f.resume([error, result]) })

  error, result = Fiber.yield

  raise error if error

  result
end
```

Example of usage:

```
action1_res = deferring(proc do 
  puts 'Async action 1'
  42
end

begin
  deferring(proc do
    puts "Action1 answered #{action1_res}"
    raise 'action2 failed'
  end)
rescue => error
  puts error
end
```

Comment: So for the sake of a simpler example, I can just call `deferring(proc1); deferring(proc2); deffering(proc3)`  ??

Comment: Also, technically, the deferred proc can complete before the call to `Fiber.yield`. what happens when you call `resume` on a fiber that's not blocked? (I realize this might be an extreme noob question)

Comment: @Ovesh, yes to your first question, it's a simplest case, without return value or error handling.

Comment: @Ovesh, I'm not 100% sure for your second question. Looking at event machine's code, I believe the result of the deferred action will be handled in a "next tick". So even if the action itself finishes before  Fiber.yield is called, the call to callback (i.e. f.resume) will be done after.

Answer (score 0):

Any code that would normally block the main reactor loop should be run using `EM#defer`.  `EM#defer` takes two blocks as arguments, the first block is run in a different thread and should not block the reactor. A second, optional block, can be passed, which will be called when the first has completed (it will also receive the result of the first block).

Further reading https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/EM::Deferrable-and-EM.defer

An example of chaining 2 long running operations would look like this:

```
logic_block = Proc.new { long_running_operation }
callback = Proc.new { |long_running_operation_result| EM.defer next_long_running_operation }

EM.defer logic_block, callback
```

Beware, The second (callback) block is run on the reactor loop, so if you're plan on chaining multiple blocks of long running code together, you'll need to call EM.defer again inside callbacks.

Comment: This is a good solution for 2 operations, but not a series of procs. I guess it's just a question of chaining proc after proc. Isn't there a good idiom to do that?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that this exact example wouldn't scale very well. The best idea i could come up with involved storing the your procs in an array, then have a simple defer operation that would shift the first proc object off the array, run it, then call itself in the completion. That would mean you could have any number of chained proc operations without the need for any extra boilerplate code to manage the chain.

Comment: I like that idea. I'm a little surprised that there's no known idiom or api for this, but I'll take your word for it.